# My JSON API call won't refresh with new data in C#. How do I clear the cache so I get fresh data?

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin

As many others here, I’m new to C# and Xamarin, but not programming in general.

I’m working on a proof of model concept where I can reach out and query stock/crypto price data and update elements in Xamarin with that data.

I have an API method called LoadData() which works right when the application launches. It updates a few Xamarin Label items with the data in their Text property.

I have a Xamarin Button object which has a Click event that triggers the same LoadData() method in the attempt that it will load in new JSON data and subsequently update the Labels with the new data.

Any subsequent LoadData() call will NOT work once it is called the first time. What I think is happening is that the original data it called gets cached, and the call doesn’t return brand NEW, fresh data.

I have spent two days looking up caching in C# trying to find the right code syntax to either clear out the JSON data before each LoadData() call, or to prevent it from caching. I have found quite a few conversations and code examples, but when I try them they either don’t work, or they appear with red underlines in Visual Studio and generate errors.

I’m going to be making a lot of these API calls and so I’m looking for the right syntax to use to solve this problem. Any help with clear code examples is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace DataBindingTest2
{

[System.ComponentModel.DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    static string IEXTrading_API_PATH = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/crypto/btcusdt/quote/1?token=TOKEN_GOES_HERE";
    static List<string> FinalPriceQuote = new List<string>(); // The LIST object to hold the final JSON data

    public string vLatestPrice = "";
    public string vCompanyName = "";
    public string vLatestVolume = "";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }


    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    public async void LoadData()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); // <-- doesn't seem to have any effect
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(IEXTrading_API_PATH))

        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        { 
            string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (data != null)
            {
                RootObject priceData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);

                FinalPriceQuote.Add(priceData.symbol.ToString());
                FinalPriceQuote.Add(priceData.latestPrice.ToString());
                FinalPriceQuote.Add(priceData.latestVolume.ToString());
                vCompanyName = FinalPriceQuote[0];
                vLatestPrice = FinalPriceQuote[1];
                vLatestVolume = FinalPriceQuote[2];

                CompanyName.Text = vCompanyName; // <-- updates Label text in XAML
                PriceLabel.Text = vLatestPrice; // <-- updates Label text in XAML
                LatestVolume.Text = vLatestVolume; // <-- updates Label text in XAML
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're always appending to `FinalPriceQuote` and reading the first 3 values., but never clearing it. Try adding `FinalPriceQuote.Clear()` before your `FinalPriceQuote.Add(...)`

Comment: Thank you ESG! I can't believe I didn't even think of that. You were right. It wasn't any cache issue, it was the list object all along that needed to be cleared. Thank you again!